# Unable to load instance config in app organized as a package

Tags: python, flask

In `__init__.py` I'm trying to load the config from a Python file relative to the instance folder.  That's throwing an error `Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): '/home/ais-flask/ais/instance/config.py'`, which is wrong, because the instance folder should be next to the package, not in it, and mine is.  I install my package in develop mode with `setup.py develop`.  I run the app with `python __init__.py`.  Why isn't this working?

```
ais-flask/
    ais/
        __init__.py
    instance/
        config.py
    setup.py
```

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your app is a package, not a single module, you need to run it with a script.  Calling `python __init__.py` messes up Python's path/package detection.  This is described in the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/).

`ais-flask/run.py`:

```
from ais import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

```
python run.py
```

---

Consider using a script runner, like Flask-Script or Flask-Cli.  This will allow you to create a runner that handles multiple commands and options.

Since you're installing the package (which is a good design pattern), you can use an entry point instead of writing the script yourself.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
manager = Manager(app)
```

In `setup.py`, add the following to the `setup` call:

```
entry_points = {'console_scripts': ['flask=ais:manager.run']}
```

This adds a `flask` command to your path while in the virtualenv.

```
flask runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__, instance_path=os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir), 'instance'), instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```